# wrap break-word at container parent, but normal at container edge

Tags: css

Say I have an outer div, and an inner div with text in it. The inner div has a fixed width narrower than the outer div.
I want the text to wrap based on spaces at the edge of the inner div, but allow long words to overflow, but wrap like `overflow-wrap: break-word;` at the edge of the outer div.

How can I accomplish this?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.outer {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.first {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.inner {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer first">
  <h2>What I get</h2>
    <div class="inner">
        Some text with a long word, Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, and some short words.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <h2>What I want</h2>
    <div class="inner">
        Some text with a long word, Supercalifragilisticex<br>pialidocious, and some short words.
    </div>
</div>
```

(And, of course, using `<br>` tags isn't an option. The width of the outer div will change.)

**EDIT:** It was suggested I include an image.
[image: A big header that looks sub-optimal]

We have a header that's supposed to wrap at 500px wide, inside a div that's `max-width: 1200px;`. I would like the word "Introduction" not to wrap, unless on a small enough screen that it reached the edge of the outer div.

We have a bunch of items which will be using this format, and we've seen a few longer words breaking like this.

Comment: not sure if it can be done ....

Comment: Me either, but a man can dream.

Comment: but what is the purpose of that, what is the real situation for this kind of feature?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). That is, you're trying to accomplish some sort of design on your page and have decided that this is the way you have to do it, however I don't think it's possible given this HTML. Perhaps tell us, visually, what you're trying to achieve, and we can tell you how to do it.

Comment: I think it isn't possible without Javascript. You can get the text and strip them and based on that what you want, add the overflow. But I'm not 100% sure what you try to achieve. Maybe a better example or image gives us more information

Comment: *Edited to include image*